# Watch Connectivity transferUserInfo never finishes, didReceiveUserInfo never called

Tags: ios, swift, watch, transfer, connectivity

I am trying to send multiple string arrays to the Apple watch companion app with the Watch Connectivity. I successfully used `updateApplicationContext` and `didReceiveApplicationContext`, but can't get `transferUserInfo` to work. I read thats it is not recommended to send large data through those, so I decided to use `transferUserInfo` instead.
For some reason, the transfer is never complete. I check the status with `wcSession?.outstandingUserInfoTransfers` and no matter how long I wait, it always contains my transfers. What is the issue here? I am assuming the session is working fine, since both messages and `updateApplicationContext` are sent and received with no problem

Comment: Are you encountering this issue only on simulators or is it reproducible on a physical pair of devices too?